# requests encoding в генераторе списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

День добрый! Имеется функция запроса :

```
def get_random_courses_list(url):
    courses_quantity = 20
    context = requests.get(url)
    courses_tree = html.fromstring(context.content)
    courses_list = courses_tree.xpath('//loc/text()')
    random_courses_list = random.sample(courses_list, courses_quantity)
    courses_raw_html_list = [[requests.get(course), 
                              course.encoding='UTF-8'] for course in 
                              random_courses_list]random_courses_list]
    return courses_raw_html_list
```

При запуске выдает ошибку:

```
   courses_raw_html_list = [[requests.get(course), course.encoding='UTF-8'] for course in random_courses_list]
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Eсли убираю кодировку:

```
courses_raw_html_list = [requests.get(course) for course in random_courses_list]
```

То все ОК, код исполняется. НО естественно кодировка не меняется. 
Что я делаю не так? Возможно ли сохранить генератор и при этом использовать `encoding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь использовать оператор присваивания (изменить поле объекта) внутри генератора списка. Синтаксисом Python это не разрешено. К тому же, даже если развернуть это в обычный цикл `for`, то `course` - это url, а не результат запроса. Пытаться изменить кодировку url запроса не имеет особого смысла.

В данном случае проще брать `content` ответа (т.е. байтовое представление текста), и декодировать его вручную:

```
courses_raw_html_list = [requests.get(course).content.decode('utf-8')
                         for course in random_courses_list]
```

Результат - список правильно декодированных строк.

Другой вариант - сначала собираем результаты get-запросов в список, потом проходимся по списку и проставляем правильную кодировку:

```
courses_raw_html_list = [requests.get(course) for course in random_courses_list]
for r in courses_raw_html_list:
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

Результат - список результатов запросов (объекты типа `Response`) с правильно проставленной кодировкой.